# I dont get expendable list view in my activity?

Tags: android

I dont get Expendable list view in my activity.
My activity contains two image views and then an expendable list view but images are shown but not list view.
Help me please.
Here I post my code.

MainActivity.java This is my main activity java file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dropdown_menu);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpendableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild) {



        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpanded(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapsed(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public long getCombinedChildId(long l, long l1) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getCombinedGroupId(long l) {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("EXOTIC AND FROZEN");
    listDataHeader.add("FRUITS");
    listDataHeader.add("VEGETABLES");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> EXOTIC = new ArrayList<String>();
    EXOTIC.add("ALL EXOTIC AND FROZEN");
    /*top250.add("The Godfather");
    top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
    top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
    top250.add("The Dark Knight");
    top250.add("12 Angry Men");*/

    List<String> FRUITS = new ArrayList<String>();
    FRUITS.add("APPLE");
    FRUITS.add("ORANGES");
    FRUITS.add("PINEAPPLE");
    FRUITS.add("BANANA");
    FRUITS.add("GRAPES");
    FRUITS.add("POMEGRANATE");

    List<String> VEG = new ArrayList<String>();
    VEG.add("CAULIFLOWER(GOBHI)");
    VEG.add("POTATOES");
    VEG.add("LADY FINGER");
    VEG.add("TOMATOES");
    VEG.add("EGG PLANT(BAINGAN)");
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), EXOTIC); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), FRUITS);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), VEG)}}
```

ExpendableListAdapter.java  This is my adapter java file

```
public class ExpendableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpendableListAdapter(Context _context,List<String> _listDataHeader,HashMap<String,List<String>> _listDataChild)
{

   this._context=_context;
   this._listDataHeader=_listDataHeader;
   this._listDataChild=_listDataChild;}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true; }}
```

dropdown_menu.xml  My main xml layout file in the project

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f4f4f4">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView22"
    android:background="@drawable/shopp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView23"
    android:background="@drawable/sa"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView22"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView23"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

list_group.xml  This is xml file for the parent in the expendable list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#000000">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?
    android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColor="#f9f93d" />
```

list_item.xml  And this is my layout file for the child of the parent

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />
```

Comment: try using listAdapter = new ExpendableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild) ;
xpListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

Comment: Thanx Gaurang its working. Can u tell me what I do wrong in my code.

Comment: i'm not sure but may be your code where you set adapter, its gets override and u get everything as null and zero.

Comment: @Hardik you created your own Anonymous class instance instead of creating the ExpendableListAdapter object from a constructor. I suggest you be careful when doing one as opposed to the other and what are the cases when to use each best. ;)

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
    listAdapter = new ExpendableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild) ;
    xpListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: you can accept answer if it helps you so that others can get help. happy coding :-)